# Question about using selenium+pyautogui to upload file

Tags: python, selenium, github, github-actions, pyautogui

Recently I need to upload my dataset on a website, the first part works fine on selenium.

However, after I click the 'upload' button, a windows file broswer pops-up.

And after searching online, I finally make it work by using pyautogui, code:

```
pyautogui.write('K:\Github\###\data\global\Global_PM_corT.csv') # enter file with path
pyautogui.press('enter') # click ok
```

My question is, I want to use above process on Github Action.

So, i changed:

```
'K:\Github\###\data\global\Global_PM_corT.csv'
```

to:

```
'./data/global/Global_PM_corT.csv'
```

and it's not working.

I think there is some error when using relative path with pyautogui.

So, i was wondering if someone could help me achieve this? Thanks in advance:)

P.S.
its working right now.

I first read the dataset by

```
pd.read_csv('path')
```

then write it on github action

```
to_csv('C:\\Global_PM_corT.csv')
```

then I can use absolute path with pyautogui:)

However, I still want to know if a better way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
'./data/global/Global_PM_corT.csv'
```

Comment: sorry, it was a typo:P I did used above relative path